# Find the distance between two locations in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, distance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distance calculation from my location to destination location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683554/distance-calculation-from-my-location-to-destination-location-in-android)

I am very new to android google maps i want display distance between two places .for that i write the two autocompletedtextview i get the from and to Locations .by using the

```
public String host = "https://maps.googleapis.com";
public String searchPath = "/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json";
public String detailsPath = "/maps/api/place/details/json";
```

I got the places names as string i want calculate the distance between two places using that two string places how can i achieve it 
    Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I use the Haversine formula, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13183753/1134705) for an example.

Comment: Try to search on stackoverflow, before posting a new question!

Comment: no i am getting two places i want find the distance based on that places ?

Answer (score 0):

To find Distance Try this just pass start and end point return you distance

```
 double distance;
 GeoPoint StartP;
 GeoPoint EndP;

    distance=CalculationByDistance(StartP,EndP);

    public double CalculationByDistance(GeoPoint StartP, GeoPoint EndP) {
            double Radius = 6371;
            double lat1 = StartP.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            double lat2 = EndP.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            double lon1 = StartP.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
            double lon2 = EndP.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
            double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
            double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            double temp = Radius * c;
            temp=temp*0.621;
            return temp;
        }
```

Comment: autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {
        
        startplace=adapter.getItem(pos);
       
          
        
        System.out.println("=========START PLACE==========="+startplace);
        
        //onPlaceSelected(adapter.getItem(pos));
       }
     });

Comment: by this i am getting the start and end places ?

Comment: how can i find distance based on these two places ?

Comment: @user1787493 get your geopoint in two diffrent variable and just pass that geopoint to this function.

Comment: how can i get lat and lang positions of the seleted places in the autocompleted textview?

Comment: @user1787493  i am not getting what you want to do. function that i have post will give you distance between two Geo point.

Comment: how can i get lat and lang postions based on place section?

Comment: @user1787493 From where you select place?

Comment: from AutocComplete Textview places list?

Comment: @user1787493 from where you place come?

Comment: public Place(String name, String reference, double lat, double lng) {
       super(name, reference);
       this.lat = lat;
       this.lng = lng;
     }

Comment: @user1787493 get lat long in on select of autocomplete view and convert that lat long to geopoint and pass that geopoint to this function.